# How to read complex data set skipping lines and with programmatic determination of the number of entries per line in R

Tags: r, database, parsing, text, import

I have many files with this structure.  The number of 4-line groups below the two header lines can vary as can the number of variables in each file. The parenthetical descriptions of the statistics are included in the file.

```
Sequence     Date     Variable1     Variable2     Variable3   ...   VariableN  
  Number     Time    
    1     Aug 23 2001    94.663        4.1672      13.11543           60.2948 (avg)  
             21:07:40     0.019        0.0013        0.0761            0.1196 (std)  
                         94.630        4.1645      13.03082           60.1196 (min)  
                         94.693        4.1689      13.27273           60.5062 (max)  
    2     Aug 23 2001    94.663        4.1672      13.11543           60.2948 (avg)  
             21:07:47     0.019        0.0013        0.0761            0.1196 (std)  
                         94.630        4.1645      13.03082           60.1196 (min)  
                         94.693        4.1689      13.27273           60.5062 (max)  

etc
```

I would like to read these files extract only the lines with the average values and create a data frame that looks something like this (though the Date variable need not include the time and I'd be happy to split the input date into separate Month Day Year variables if need be):

```
Sequence         Date Variable1 Variable2 Variable3 ... VariableN  
       1   08-23-2001    94.663    4.1672  13.11543       60.2968  
       2   08-23-2001    94.663    4.1672  13.11543       60.2968  
etc
```

Skipping lines to read only the average value lines isn't really a problem.  I can count the number of lines in the data file, subtract the two header lines, and divide the difference by four to get the number of observations.  I thought I could use a loop with the scan() function to then read the data line, then append the output list elements to a data frame and return the data frame.  For example this psuedo-R code,

```
# Create a list for the scan function; simplify by reading date elements as separate variables
#
thisList <- list(Sequence=numeric(0), Month=character(0), Day=numeric(0), Year=numeric(0),
                 Variable1=numeric(0), Variable2=numeric(0), Variable3=numeric(0), Stat=character(0)
#
# Loop through the observation blocks and read the data line
#
for (i in 1:nObs){
  thisLine <- scan(infile, skip=(nHead-2)+(i-1)*4, nlines=1, what=thisList)
  outFrame <- rbind(outFrame,as.data.frame(thisLine))
}
```

This doesn't seem to work.  The returned data frame is NULL.  Furthermore, if scan() is the right function to use, I don't know how to determine the number of entries to include in the "want" list dynamically as needed for the different files.  I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: What is the format of the data you are reading in (e.g. Excel file)?  If you have already read into R, can you do ```dput(head(df,10))``` (where ```df``` is the name of your dataframe and replace 10 with the number of lines of your dataframe you want to include that would help show your format?

Comment: Hello Russ.  The files I am reading are just ASCII text.  I don't understand the rest of your comment.   The toy example I included in my original query is my attempt to mimic the format of the files to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Apologies @Fleetboat, I thought you were reading in an excel file or similar. I just posted my shot at an answer below using an ascii text file based on the format listed in your questions (note: I removed the ```...``` in the first row.

Comment: No need to apologize, Russ.  Thanks for your suggestion.  I appreciate you thinking about it and offering your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option reading in the input as an ascii text file per your comment above as `test.txt` (see bottom of answer for format used)

---

**Code**

```
library(gsubfn)  # For read.pattern function
library(stringr) # For str_extract_all function
library(anytime) # For anytime function


# text input saved as text.txt
# Read in text file
newlines <- readLines("test.txt", warn = FALSE)

# Read in first line of text file as string to get column names 
first_row <- readLines("test.txt", n = 1)

# Extract column names as a vector
# \\S matches a non-space character
col_names <- str_extract_all(first_row, "\\S+")[[1]]

# create dataframe containing only rows ending in the pattern "avg)"
df_averages <- read.pattern(text = newlines,as.is = TRUE,  pattern = ".*[avg]\\)")

# create regex pattern to extract all values from each row
pattern_regex <- "^(\\s+\\d+) +(\\S+\\w\\s+\\d+\\s+\\d+) +(\\S+) +(\\S+) +(\\S+) +(\\S+)"

# Create final dataframe format with all variables and named with column names from the first line of test.txt
df_final <- read.pattern(text = df_averages$V1, pattern = pattern_regex, as.is = TRUE, col.names=col_names )

# Convert "Date" variable to actual date class
df_final$Date <- anytime(df_final$Date)
```

---

**Output**

```
> df_final
  Sequence       Date Variable1 Variable2 Variable3 VariableN
1        1 2001-08-23    94.663    4.1672  13.11543   60.2948
2        2 2001-08-23    94.663    4.1672  13.11543   60.2948
```

---

```
> str(df_final)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Sequence : int  1 2
 $ Date     : POSIXct, format: "2001-08-23" "2001-08-23"
 $ Variable1: num  94.7 94.7
 $ Variable2: num  4.17 4.17
 $ Variable3: num  13.1 13.1
 $ VariableN: num  60.3 60.3
```

---

**test.txt input**

```
Sequence     Date     Variable1     Variable2     Variable3      VariableN  
  Number     Time    
    1     Aug 23 2001    94.663        4.1672      13.11543        60.2948 (avg)  
             21:07:40     0.019        0.0013        0.0761         0.1196 (std)  
                         94.630        4.1645      13.03082        60.1196 (min)  
                         94.693        4.1689      13.27273        60.5062 (max)  
    2     Aug 23 2001    94.663        4.1672      13.11543        60.2948 (avg)  
             21:07:47     0.019        0.0013        0.0761         0.1196 (std)  
                         94.630        4.1645      13.03082        60.1196 (min)  
                         94.693        4.1689      13.27273        60.5062 (max)
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing around I found a solution.  This may not be the most elegant, but it works for me.  The code uses the str_squish function from the stringr package.

```
    nObs    <- (nData-2)/4                                                         # count the number of observations
    
    header    <- scan(inFile, skip= nHead, nlines= 1, what= character(0))          # get the column names
    header    <- c(header[1], 'Month', 'Day', 'Year', header[3:(nSensors+1)])      # include variable names to deal with date
    
    data      <- inLines[(nHead+3):nLines]                                         # extract the data lines
    avgLines  <- grep(pattern='(avg)', x=data)                                     # extract the indices of the average lines in the data
    avgData   <- trimws(data[avgLines])                                            # extract the average lines and trim white space
    avgFrame  <- as.data.frame(avgData)                                            # convert to data frame (nobs x 1 variable)
    outFrame  <- data.frame()
    for (i in 1:nObs) {
       thisLine <- str_squish(avgFrame[i,])                                        # get rid of extra white space
       spltLine <- strsplit(thisLine, " ")                                         # split the line into components
       ncomps   <- length(spltLine[[1]])
       for (j in 1:ncomps){
        outFrame[i,j] <- spltLine[[1]][j]                                          # populate data frame
       }
     }
     outFrame    <- outFrame[,-ncomps]                                             # drop "(avg)"
     outFrame$V1 <- as.numeric(outFrame$V1)                                        # fix the type of column 1
     for (k in 3:(ncomps-1)) {
        outFrame[,k] <- as.numeric(outFrame[,k])                                   # fix the types of the other numeric columns
     }
     colnames(outFrame) <- header                                                  # assign the header names
    return(outFrame)
```